# Combine two ranges to give name and hyperlink

Tags: go, go-html-template

I am trying to create a hyperlink attached to a name, however both groups are in two separate ranges i.e. names are in one range and the links are in another.  Is there a way to combine the two?  Currently the html code I have is as below, however, I want only the name to contain the hyperlink.

```
 <h5 class="card-title">Members:</h5>
   {{range .Members}}
   <ul class="card-text">
      <li style="margin-bottom: 0rem;">{{.}}</li>
   <./ul>
   {{end}}
   <h5 class="card-title">WikiLink:</h5>
     {{range .WikiLink}}
     <ul class=" card-text">
       <li style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"><a href="{{.}}">{{.}}</a></li>
     </ul>
     {{end}}
```

The output I am therefore getting is a list of names and then a list of links below.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is this syntax? is it `Go`, `HTML`? Are you trying to write `Go` code inside of `HTML` file?

Comment: @rosmak, yes, it's highly Go-specific. The syntax is [here](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template) in case you're curious ;-) I've retagged the question properly.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this I am creating a web page using Go and HTML?  the code above is from a HTML file but the ranges are from Go - sorry if I'm not being very clear not sure how to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `WikiLink` array by index in the template:

```golang
 <h5 class="card-title">Members:</h5>
   {{range $i, $m :=.Members}}
   <ul class="card-text">
      <li style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"><a href="{{index $.WikiLink $i}}">{{$m}}</a></li>
   </ul>
 {{end}}
```

Working example in Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/PKD-o3y09sk